# Can you declare an anonymous instance of a named struct?

Tags: c, anonymous-struct

I'm trying to manually implement a polymorphic behavior in C by creating a generic struct, and then *derived structs* (if you will) which can be told apart by the value of an enum, so that I can have a pointer to the generic type, dereference it as the generic type, figure out what type it is, and then dereference it as the more specific type.

```
typedef struct{
  enum type structType;
  //... other stuff all the structs share
}generic;

typedef struct{
  generic; //does not work, obviously, nor does (generic){};
  //... other stuff unique to struct type A
}typeA;
```

I understand that I could just declare a named instance of the generic struct in the derived struct, but this seems a little messy, and I would prefer not to if there's a neat and tidy way around it.

Comment: The way people generally do this kind of polymorphism is with a union.

Comment: Why do you use anonymous structs at all?

Comment: `this seems a little messy` naming a member of structure is messy?

Comment: Your code actually works with `MSVC` and `clang-cl`, but with this: **warning : anonymous structs are a Microsoft extension [-Wmicrosoft-anon-tag]**!

Comment: gcc also allows this if Microsoft extensions are enabled via `-fms-extensions` see gcc documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html#Unnamed-Fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can't always get what you want, but if you try sometimes, well, you might find, you get what you need ...

There are two basic ways, with a slight bit of trickery:

1. Using an include file (e.g.): `generic.h`
2. Using a CPP macro (e.g): `GENERIC`

I've used both methods at various times.

---

Here's the method with the include file (`generic.h`):

```
enum type structType;
int com_fd;
void *com_buf;
```

And, here's a `.c` file that uses it:

```
typedef struct {
#include <generic.h>
} generic;

typedef struct {
#include <generic.h>
    // other stuff unique to struct type A ...
    int typea_value;
} typeA;
```

---

Here's the method using a macro:

```
#define GENERIC \
    enum type structType; \
    int com_fd; \
    void *com_buf

typedef struct {
    GENERIC;
} generic;

typedef struct {
    GENERIC;

    // other stuff unique to struct type A ...
    int typea_value;
} typeA;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can you declare an anonymous instance of a named struct?

No.

Yet code can make-up a name based on the line number, to keep it unique and with some level of animosity.

Now code should not try to reference `var.member11` as the member's name changes as the code for `typeA` definition moves about in the file.

```
#define ANON_1(A,B) A##B
#define ANON_2(A,B) ANON_1(A,B)
#define ANON ANON_2(member, __LINE__)

typedef struct{
  int x;
} generic;

typedef struct{
  generic ANON; // name will be something like: member10
  generic ANON; // name will be something like: member11
  int y;
} typeA;

int main() {
  typeA var;
  (void) var;
  return 0;
}
```

---

I suspect though to achieve OP's higher goal, a better approach is possible.